# Неправильно работает добавление юзера в выпадающий список

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Требуется добавить новое имя в выпадающий список (используется *ui-grid*). Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку *addNewPerson* бралось значение по *id* из поля ввода и «пушилось» в выпадающий список, если такого имени ещё нет. Если же такое имя имеется, то должен вызываться `alert`.

Вот кусок кода, отвечающий за создание выпадающего списка в *html*:

```
<ui-select ng-model="person.selected" theme="select2" style="min-width:300px;">

<ui-select-match placeholder="Select a person in the list or search by name">{{$select.selected.name}}
        </ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="person in contacts | filter: {name: $select.search} track by $index">
            <div ng-bind-html="person.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
        </ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>
```

Кнопка и поле ввода:

```
<button type="button" id="addPerson" class="button" ng-  click="addNewPerson()">Add New Person</button>

<input id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Name">
```

Массив объектов contacts с полем name, который передаётся в выпадающий    список:

```
    $scope.contacts = [
    {name: "Han Solo"},
    {name: "ThetaSigma"},
    {name: "Ollie Reeder"},
    {name: "Amy McDonald"},
    {name: "PJ Harvey"},
    {name: "Sofie Marceau"},
    {name: "Arthur Zimmermann"},
    {name: "Michelle Dockery"},
    {name: "Xavier Dolan"}
];
```

И, наконец, функция, отвечающая за добавление:

```
$scope.person = {};

    $scope.addNewPerson = function () {
    var nameInput = document.getElementById("name");

    for (var i=0; i <= $scope.contacts.length; i++) {

        if ($scope.contacts[i].name == nameInput.value.toLowerCase()) {
            alert("Error, the name entered already exists");
        }else{
            var obj1 = {name: nameInput.value};
            $scope.contacts.push(obj1);
        }
    }

};
```

Пока данная функция ничего не добавляет и выдаёт 10 раз alert, не понимаю, почему.

Comment: Вы лучше алерт сравниваемых значений сделайте.

Answer (score 1):

В Angular всегда используйте двустороннее связывание вместо прямого доступа к элементу. Т.е. тут надо поменять вот это: `var nameInput = document.getElementById("name")` и `nameInput.value.toLowerCase()` на `$scope.userName` и `<input ng-model="userName">` , внеся соответствующие изменения в шаблон и всюду, где сейчас сделано подобным образом.

Comment: Попробую сделать так, спасибо. Отпишусь о результатах.

Comment: Пробовал следующее: пихать на место    var nameInput = document.getElementById("name"); $scope.userName =" ";  
и также просто   $scope.userName. То же пытался вынести за фуекцию как глоб. переменную.  В любом случае выдаёт:
ReferenceError: userName is not defined

Comment: Я сделал так:  `$scope.userName = "";  

    $scope.addNewPerson = function () {
        var name =$scope.userName; 
        var match_found = false;  
        for (var i=0; i <= $scope.contacts.length; i++) {  

            if ($scope.contacts[i].name == name.toLowerCase()) {  
                alert("Error, the name entered already exists");  
                match_found = true;  
                break;  
            }  
        }  

        if (!match_found) {
            var obj1 = {name:$scope.name};
            $scope.contacts.push(obj1);
        }

    };`

Comment: PS: прошу прощения за неудобоваримый код в верхнем комментарии.
Мне упорно выдаётся ошибка Cannot read property 'name' of undefined, несмотря на `<input ng-model="userName" id="name1" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Name">`
На форумы ходил, гуглил, но всё равно не понимаю, отчего может возникать ошибка.